# Fancybox v2 close dialog with html button in the content

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying to close a fancybox dialog with a html button in the content without using helpers or tpl. But with no success.

```
var modal = function () { 
   $.fancybox({
      'minHeight'  : 100,
      'autoScale'  : true,
      'autoSize'   : true,
      'autoHeight' : true,
      'autoWidth'  : true,
      'fitToView'  : true,
      'closeBtn'   : false,
      'modal'      : true,
       beforeShow: function()
       {
            $('#modal').html(msg);
       }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="open">OPEN</div>
<div id="modal"></div>
```

My CODE

```
$('#open').on('click', function ()
{
    var btn = '<br><a href="javascript:;">Close</a>';
    modal("here the html content" + btn);
});
```

How could you do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do some tweaks to your code.

1. Since you are calling `modal` like this

   ```
   modal("here the html content" + btn);
   ```

   ... you need to pass the *parameters* within the *function* like

   ```
   var modal = function(msg) { ... }
   ```
2. Regardless you are filling the `#modal` container like

   ```
   $('#modal').html(msg);
   ```

   ... you still need to tell fancybox to **target** that container as the fancybox content by adding the `href` API option like :

   ```
   href: "#modal"
   ```

   BTW use the `beforeLoad` callback instead of `beforeShow` to fill the content with the `.html()` method like

   ```
   beforeLoad: function () {
       $('#modal').html(msg);
   }
   ```
3. Your `btn`  *object* is missing to target the `$.fancybox.close()` method on `click` so change it to :

   ```
   var btn = '<br><a href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.close();">Close</a>';
   ```

So your final code should look like :

```
var modal = function(msg) {
    $.fancybox({
        minHeight: 100,
        // autoScale: true, // not a valid option for v2.x
        autoSize: true,
        // autoHeight: true, // not needed since autoSize is true
        // autoWidth: true,
        fitToView: true,
        // closeBtn: false, // not needed since modal is true
        modal: true,
        href: "#modal",
        beforeLoad: function () {
            $('#modal').html(msg);
        }
    });
}
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#open').on('click', function () {
        var btn = '<br><a href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.close();">Close</a>';
        modal("here the html content" + btn);
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t5jyzuk2/)**

**Notice**  the comments on some API options

Comment: Just use a jQuery `click` event handler instead of the inline JavaScript.  Then you could add a `preventDefault()` to prevent the anchor from acting like an anchor... prevent the page from potentially jumping and prevent adding the link to browser history.

Comment: @Sparky : since the close `click` event is only required within the fancybox context, I would rather bind it within the `afterShow` callback http://jsfiddle.net/t5jyzuk2/2/. Anyways, the inline javascript is created dynamically and only after opening fancybox. Don't see the point to argue what method is better though. My 5 cents.

Comment: This site is about "quality answers" and comments are primarily about pointing out areas of improvement in that regard.  I merely made a valid point that both inline JS and allowing a "close" click into browser history are ugly/unnecessary when using jQuery.  Take it or leave it, but my comment is here to help any future readers that care to follow along.